# mariadb install error case - Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully You can try again using: brew postinstall mariadb

Tags: mysql, installation, mariadb, homebrew

I'm using a Mac m1.
It used homebrew.
I installed mysql before.

When i run the command 'brew install mariadb',

---

```
*****@*****ui-MacBookAir  ~  brew install mariadb
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/mariadb/manifests/10.8.3_1
Already downloaded: /Users/isihwa/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/8ffe301e8a1ef3b1098a896043bf3db68fecbe8094768ea4462cd9bf98382e2f--mariadb-10.8.3_1.bottle_manifest.json
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/mariadb/blobs/sha256:44ff9ff617ada03c556166db35991f5f0a8ae98ad1db14fd215cc66255964a48
Already downloaded: /Users/isihwa/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/07df8179fdce7cbd416ed476a175969de988f3c50167c64bfc7e0be8667f897d--mariadb--10.8.3_1.arm64_monterey.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring mariadb--10.8.3_1.arm64_monterey.bottle.tar.gz
==> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mariadb/10.8.3_1/bin/mysql_install_db --verbose --user=isihwa --basedir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mariadb/10.8.3_1 --datadir=/opt/homebrew/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp
Last 15 lines from /Users/isihwa/Library/Logs/Homebrew/mariadb/post_install.01.mysql_install_db:

shell> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mariadb/10.8.3_1/bin/mysql -u root mysql
mysql> show tables;

Try 'mysqld --help' if you have problems with paths. Using
--general-log gives you a log in /opt/homebrew/var/mysql that may be helpful.

The latest information about mysql_install_db is available at
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-system-tables-mysql_install_db
You can find the latest source at https://downloads.mariadb.org and
the maria-discuss email list at https://launchpad.net/~maria-discuss

Please check all of the above before submitting a bug report
at https://mariadb.org/jira

Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using:
brew postinstall mariadb
==> Caveats
A "/etc/my.cnf" from another install may interfere with a Homebrew-built
server starting up correctly.

MySQL is configured to only allow connections from localhost by default

To restart mariadb after an upgrade:
brew services restart mariadb
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
/opt/homebrew/opt/mariadb/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/opt/homebrew/var/mysql
==> Summary
 /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mariadb/10.8.3_1: 915 files, 174.6MB
==> Running `brew cleanup mariadb`...
Disable this behaviour by setting HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP.
Hide these hints with HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_HINTS (see `man brew`).
✘ *****@*****aui-MacBookAir  ~ 
```

---

It is said that it failed like this. And brew postinstall mariadb is told to do this.
Googling found out that the existing files were not completely erased
I executed the following command to completely delete the original mysql.

```
'brew uninstall mysql'
'sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew/var/mysql'
'sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew/bin/mysql*'
'sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql'
```

After that, I installed mariadb again
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using:
brew postinstall mariadb
Warnings keep coming out. Do you know how to solve this?